# Problem with connection in R to DB2-database

Tags: r, db2

we have a very weird problem when we try to query any table in our DB2-database from R using ODBC. Two different databases (Microsoft SQL) works as a charm. This error only happens on 1 of 4 in our team and regardless which DB2-user we use.

A simple code to get some data

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)


con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "ourDSN", uid = "kUsername", pwd = "kPwd")
dbGetQuery(con,"Select * FROM OURSCHEMA.TABLE1")
```

But while this works like a charm for my other colleagues, it doesn't work for one of us.

We get the following error-code:

```
error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: HY000: [IBM][System i Access ODBC-driver][DB2 for i5/OS]
Error message no available. The error message cannot be converted
```

That last line is translated, since it comes in another language than English

This is the connection info from the malfunctioning :

```
Formal class 'DB2/400 SQL' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 4 slots
..@ ptr :<externalptr>
..@ quote : chr "\""
..@ info :List of 15 
.. ..$ dbname : chr "OurDBName"
.. ..$ dbms.name : chr "DB2/400 SQL"
.. ..$ db.version : chr "07.04.0015"
.. ..$ username : chr "USER"
.. ..$ host : chr ""
.. ..$ port : chr ""
.. ..$ sourcename : chr "OurSourceName"
.. ..$ servername : chr "OurServerName"
.. ..$ drivername : chr "CWBODBC.DLL"
.. ..$ odbc.version : chr "03.80.0000"
.. ..$ driver.version : chr "07.01.0000"
.. ..$ odbcdriver.version : chr "03.51"
.. ..$ supports.transactions : logi TRUE
.. ..$ getdata.extensions.any_column: logi TRUE
.. ..$ getdata.extensions.any_order : logi TRUE
.. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "DB2/400 SQL" "driver_info" "list"
..@ encoding: chr ""


OS IBM i 7.4
ODBC Driver 13.00.01.00 

Work station system:
R version 4.2.0 Patched (2022-05-12 r82348 ucrt) -- "Vigorous 
Calisthenics"
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Nothing here seperates our connection-info. We have the same version of R and the same OS (windows 10). All packages are up-to date.

Both our IT and we ourselves are scratching our heads. At the moment our 3 only options are

1. System reset
2. Scrubing the computer and re-installing everything
3. New computer

We have tried re-installing the drivers but to no avail. Anyone have an idea what is wrong?

UPDATE:

Reverting to older version of R (august 2021) makes the problem disappear.

Comment: Do you really use Db2 on IBM i (AS/400) or some other platform? Add details on your Db2 platform and version. Are you all using the same ODBC driver and configuration?

Comment: Yeah - the same ODBC-driver and configuration. For the DB2 platform I'll have to check with our IT-department.

Comment: If you are not even sure which type of Db2 your are using, then I would recommend to clarify the basics.

Comment: Please edit your question to show which operating-system(s) (and their versions/bitness/editions) are running R. You have working systems and failing systems. Determine the differences between the two. If the i-series access driver version is identical, then the environment variables (and/or locale details) probably differ on the working versus failing machines. Use only the latest supported version of the i-series access for Microsoft-windows driver.

Comment: @mao yeah, that's what were aiming for. Our working stations are exactly the same atleast on paper. The same drivers, same version of R, up-to-date packages. We know something happened with the last update to R and R-Studio for this user but we can't see how this problem arises.

Comment: @ErrantBard  competent troubleshooting required. The message "Error message no available. The error message cannot be converted " is almost always a configuration screw-up.  Sometimes if there is more than one version of the driver installed, or more than one driver (e.g. one clidriver, one i aceess driver) or improper environment-variables - this symptom results. Tracing of the driver (even independently of R) can often show the cause, to suitably experienced people.  This is not a programming question. Sometimes re-imaging the workstation with a known-good image is fastest.

Comment: @mao thx - yeah, we've started to suspect that. Might be something with 32/64 bit drivers? A revert to older version of R made the problem go away know.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by re-install the iSeries Access ODBC Driver via the ACS Windows App Pkg English (64bit) download.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/odbc-driver-ibm-i-access-client-solutions